# Why does a package archive produce error "not an absolute file name"?

Tags: init-file, package

When starting an older Emacs (23.4, say) for testing, I get an error from package initialisation a certain package is not available for installation. `list-packages` also shows a failure but with no details.

Starting with `--debug-init` shows that the error is:

```
(error "Archive location https://melpa.org/packages/ is not an absolute file name")
```

What causes this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This misleading error is due to `string-match`ing the URL against "http:" - essentially HTTPS is not supported by `package-legacy.el`.

Arguably this is also a bug in `cask.el` (which only uses HTTPS) but I'm not sure if they already dropped support for Emacs 23.

Comment: Cask [doesn't support Emacs 23](http://cask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/installation.html#prerequisites) anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I still had a package.el in my emacs config from when I was using Emacs 23, and even now that I'm on Emacs 24 it was still using the "vendored" package.el. Deleting that file fixed my issue.